# Searching for matching URL in database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I could find many similar cases but not exactly helpful for mine.
I have 2 structures:

```
-> Users
    ->uid1
    ->uid2
      ->userdata
        ->fileName : "www.google.com"

-> Tags
    ->tagName1
    ->tagName2
      ->fileName : "www.google.com"
```

In Users structure I keep all necessary info about user with urls to a files they post. 
Tags structure is just a simple structure which hold information about files that were tagged.

So my problem is deletion of the fileName and url in Tags structure.
When user deletes a file I know where to look for (Users structure) but I want to also check Tags structure and delete the reference there as well.
To sum it up, i know what is file name and it's url, but i don't know how can i search through different tags to find the one that match.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can tag point only to a single file name? From you structure, it looks like a tag has property fileName holding URL to the file.

Comment: Each tag can can have multiple "files" linked to it. So each file is described as file name and it's url. Url is necessary for me at this place to open file in the app.

Comment: What is the use case? I understand that you need to display files with a given tags, that's why you have tags node?

Comment: Exaclty. I display tags with associated files on the screen.

Comment: When deleting the file I am given its name, right?

Comment: That's right. Url and file name